# Как указать TextView, занимающий ширину, только которую использует?

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Текст1 Текст1 Текст1 Текст1"
        android:maxWidth="280dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Текст2 Текст2"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вот как он выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`textView1` занимает больше места, чем ему необходимо (есть свободное пространство справа) и `textView2` точно не поместится в одну сточку, хотя мог бы попробовать. Как указать `textView1`, чтобы занимал ширину, только которую использует?

**UPD**

Вот как должен выглядеть экран, если `textView1` занимает немного места, поэтому использование `android:layout_weight` не выйдет для различных плотностей экранов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ещё картинку как надо чтобы выглядело при большом тексте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит из за атрибута `android:maxWidth`. Так как размер по ширине задан `wrap_content`, то виджет пытается вместить весь текст как можно больше по ширине и в вашем случае ширина виджета при этом получается больше указанного значения `maxWidth ="280dp"`, поэтому она ограниченна указанным вами значением в `280dp`.

То есть, расчетная ширина для данного текста больше, чем указанная максимальная ширина и за ширину для виджета принимается максимальная разрешенная , а место остается из-за переноса по целым словам, а не слогам.

Решить этот вопрос так, как вам хочется ( ограничение занимаемого размера по месту переноса, если перенос происходит ближе текущего размера) невозможно для стандартного виджета.

Замечу, что для пропорционального деления экрана лучше использовать веса (атрибут `android:layout_weight`) так как указание хардкорной ширины в единицах  плотности приведет к тому, что на разных устройствах разметка будет выглядеть не одинаково из за того, что у разных экранов разные плотности - на экране hdpi это будет почти вся ширина, а на xxhdpi чуть больше половины.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. По поводу использования android:layout_weight, он мне не подойдет, так как как если textView1 занимает по ширине немного(например одно слово), тогда textView2 должен находится, сразу справа от него.

Comment: Но использование android:maxWidth = плотностям для разных экранов действительно будет некорректно отображаться, тогда получается необходимо наверное использовать значение android:maxWidth для различных плотностей.